# Adding Google Maps with KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, google-maps, knockout.js

I have following part in my html file.

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDwsTgxJyu7KG7BPM3q54mgjSHl1imLnCM&sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        require(["Work/AddCiniViewModel"], function (model) {
            addCiniViewModel = new model();
            addCiniViewModel.createMap();
            ko.applyBindings(addCiniViewModel, document.getElementById("AddCiniForm"));
            }
        });
```

I have following part in my ViewModel file.

```
 self.map;
        self.Lng = ko.observable(12.24);
        self.Lat = ko.observable(24.54);

        self.createMap = function () {
            var elevator;
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 3,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(12.24, 24.54),
                mapTypeId: 'terrain'
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map($('#map')[0], myOptions);
        }


        ko.bindingHandlers.map = {
            init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, addCiniViewModel) {


                var position = new google.maps.LatLng(allBindingsAccessor().latitude(),
                    allBindingsAccessor().longitude());

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: allBindingsAccessor().map,
                    position: position,
                    title: name
                });

                self._mapMarker = marker;
            },
            update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, addCiniViewModel) {
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(allBindingsAccessor().latitude(), allBindingsAccessor().longitude());
                self._mapMarker.setPosition(latlng);

            }
        };
```

And I would like to see google maps and its lat long values in the following div.

```
<div id="map"></div>
            <input data-bind="value: Lat" />
            <input data-bind="value: Lng" />
            <div data-bind=" style: style:{width:'300px',height:'300px'}, 
                latitude: addCiniViewModel.Lat, longitude:addCiniViewModel.Lng, map:map">
            </div>
```

When I run this code. I got this message in firebug.
google.maps.LatLng is not a constructor

What's wrong? How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps API javascript is loading asynchronously while execution of your code is continuing. Your code then uses the Maps API before it is available.

To wait for the Maps API you can wrap your ko.applyBindings call inside a jQuery onload event handler

```
$(window).load(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(addCiniViewModel, document.getElementById("AddCiniForm"));
});
```

Here is another example from Google on how to wait for the maps API before initializing code that uses it: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial